# Issue accessing domain pc from local pc after entering incorrect username/password

Tags: security, active-directory, local

I'm using windows 7 local account, I have admin domain credentials too.

I must have entered them incorrectly when accessing a domain pc (to get to a share) and now any time I try to access the pc, the following message is instantly displayed:

> \\pc-name is not accessible. You might
>   not have permission to use this
>   network resource....
>
> Logon Failure: The target account name
>   is incorrect

I googled this and it mentions something to do with net bios, though I can't see why that is the problem... it is as if the pc has cached the wrong credentials and isn't asking for them again. anyone else had to get around this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the domain pc not pointing to the correct DNS Server

Answer (score 1):

You could try clearing any cached credentials with: net use /d *

Or alternatively: net use /d //servername/share

The former of which will clear all cached credentials, rather than only one specific share.